# ASP.NET MVC API crashes when 2 users make a query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an IIS configured with an ASP.NET application for an API.

When 2 users make the same API call at the same time, it crashes and we don't get any response from the API.

The IIS version is 10 and I'm running it on a Windows Server 2019

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, how are you calling the api? There is also information about the crash of the application, please post more details information about your issue.